# Use of SMS or Call Log permission groups - play console warning

Tags: android, sms, call, policy

In the past we did request the `android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS` but in the latest release we have removed this permission in order to be compliant with [google's new policy](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9047303).

Few days ago, I see this warning in the play console:

[image]

I was surprised because I thought we already have a compliant app. Looking through play console tabs, I see under Release Management -> Artifact Library -> Active artifacts, tab that we still had an old apk that was active and it did contain the RECEIVE_SMS permission.

I managed to disable this old apk and was waiting for the warning to go away.

It didn't go away and I'm not sure what is wrong, if anything.

We do not request any of the restricted permissions, I've checked against the [source code](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml).

This is the merged manifest that we have.

Does anybody else have this problem?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that anyone of used Libraries do not use these Permissions? Your Manifest (in the project tree) only show the Permissions YOU EXPLICITELY request but not those Library requires by themself. You have to extract the Manifest from the final APK to see the Merged Manifest and be sure that Permissions are not used.

Comment: the image that I've attached its of the merged manifest.

Comment: the warning has disappeared from play console now, 1 day later.

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. Uploaded a new build yesterday after removing the permissions. But still, the warning hasn't gone. Link for permissions used is https://drive.google.com/file/d/1amCNHnTae0O6fixVyP0wWyABG88rpK5u/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Do we need to fill the Permission Declaration Form even after removal of permission?

Comment: Apparently it takes some time for the play console and play store to acknowledge the changes. I my case the warning went away after 2 days from the time we removed the retained apk that contained the restricted permission.

Comment: "I managed to disable this old apk " May I know how can we disable the old apk from Active artifacts ? @GoranHoriaMihail

Comment: From what I remember, I think I did it from App releases tab. It was a apk that was uploaded to the Internal test track.

Comment: @GoranHoriaMihail Yes, Actually I am stuck at the same point and need to deactivate the previous version from play store but I am confused. I am having the same apk in internal test track but active in artifact please guide me how to remove or give update on the same apk.